# How do I add a label or keyword to my Google Scholar account?

Tags: google-scholar

I notice that some people have labels or keywords associated with their Google Scholar profile - e.g., biochemistry, DNA, etc.
How do I add these to my profile?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

On your profile page while beeing logged in: click on the "pen" icon to edit your profile, then add keywords separated by `,` in the field "Areas of interest"